# Error de publicación ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, api, ssl

Buenas noches tengo el siguiente error se presenta debido a que publique mi pagina web en un servidor con certificado de seguridad y tengo mi API en otro servidor que no tiene certificado ni dominio, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para solucionar este problema. Gracias por su apoyo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola el error te lo tira el navegador, ya que como te menciona el mensaje, no deberias llamar un sitio con http desde un sitio el cual esta sobre https, aca tienes varias opciones :

1. Hacer que tu api corra sobre https
2. Algunos navegadores te permiten habilitar el uso de contenido seguro en tus paginas (Opcion no recomendable).
3. Instalar un servidor proxy que te rediriga ejemplo : nginx el cual puedes tener un certificado autofirmado, pero esto seria mas trabajo que la opcion 1.